# How to know when a command has been invoked on UserControl?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I need to do some visual effects on the control after a particular ICommand was executed. For example, my Custom control exposes AAACommand and BBBCommand properties.

```
<myControl AAACommand={Binding ACommand}
           BBBCommand={Binding BCommand} />
```

where ACommand and BCommand are Commands on ViewModel. How do I know when AAACommand was executed, so I can do some UI stuff in my UserControl? there is no Executed event for ICommand to subscribe to.

**Edit:** AAACommand is defined like this on my user control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AAACommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AddCommand", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(MyCustomControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty AAACommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AAACommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(MyCustomControl), null);

public RelayCommand AAACommand
{
    get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(AAACommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AAACommandProperty, value); }
}

public object AAACommandParameter
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(AAACommandParameterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AAACommandParameterProperty, value); }
}
```

So, there is no problem in invoking ACommand on ViewModel, this works without problem. The problem is how will my user control know when AAACommand will execute ACommand, so it can do something with its UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the usercontrol based upon a response returned from the view model and the command executed? I asked a question similar in nature where I wanted to pass as string value from one user control to another user control. I accomplished this using INotifyProperty Changed event. You can read the original question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115994/passing-a-string-from-one-user-control-to-a-second-user-control-via-inotify-wiht)

**Update to comment:**

Base on your comment it seems like one of two things could happen. If you don't need the VM to respond then the update could be triggered by elements in the view. You could do this using Binding ElementNameProperty. This in essence allows you to trigger/change a property based upon the action of another element. (typing text in one field displays the value in another control) [Here is the msdn description and example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) .

If you need it to be invoked based upon the return (i.e. success or failure) then the ViewModel will need to have a property (like a bool) that is bound two-way to the property of the element in the ui. 
You may need to create a converter (inheriting [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) ) to handle the binding but INotifyProp Change would be used to marshal the update between the controls or the bound elements within them.

Here is a quick example:

within my xaml I added a user control that I did not want to be visible within the UI until another button within a secondary usercontrol was clicked. To handle this I setup binding on the Visibility property

```
<ctrl:LandingPage x:Name="ucLandingPage"
                                  Grid.Row="1" 
                                  DataContext="{Binding}"  
                                  Visibility="{Binding LandingPageVisibility, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource LandingPageVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Within the viewmodel I had the following property and code

```
// Default ctor
        public SearchViewModel()  
        {
            //Show that the Landing Page control is being displayed
            SearchVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

property in VM (note I use SimpleMVVM framework which has Inotify included in the base object so my notify prop event may look a bit different from yours)

```
 private Visibility _SearchVisibility;
            public Visibility SearchVisibility
            {
                get { return _SearchVisibility; }
                set
                {
                    _SearchVisibility = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SearchVisibility);
                }
            }
```

Then the method within the VM that updated this property

```
 public void GetSearchResult()
        {
            currentPage = 1;
            //Set the visibility of the search control in the center of the page
            SearchVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.SearchHistory = this._DataModel.AddSearchHistoryItem(this.SearchTerm);
        }
```

And finally the converter class which would convert the return value to the correct property value for the element

```
  public class SearchVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null & System.Convert.ToString(value) == "Visible")
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, I dont care what the ViewModel responed. I just want to do this on my UserControl: invoke a Command, and after execute a custom logic, which is not related to VIewModel result. The action on my UserControl, could be, for example, expand something, or color something in red, etc... There must be some way to intercept command on UI, since there is a wiring mechanism in it.

Comment: @Goran I have updated my comment with further explanation example hope this helps

Comment: I cannot use ElementName because there is no UI element that I can bind to. And there is no return value from the Command. I guess the solution lies in CommandManager, but I could not find a solution to it yet. The last resort would be to modify RelayCommand implementation, since it is from MVVM light framework, so source code is available.

Comment: @Goran since you are using MVVM light have you looked at the messenger api?  http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Comment: That would probably be the worst solution of the offered ones. Best solution would be not to have a dependency on MVVM Light at all, but if I cannot find any other solution, I would just subclass the RelayCommand, wrap Execute method, so I could just call base.Execute(), and then raise Executed event.